# If we can store images (user images, product images, etc.) in databases (e.g. MongoDB), then why should we use cloudinary to store the images?

Tags: mongodb

If we can store images (user images, product images, etc.) in databases (e.g. MongoDB), then why should we use cloudinary to save images?

Comment: It's up to you. Ask the person who told you that you should use cloudinary  what are their arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be compared to relation between RAM and HDD.

Of course, DB and cloudinary both are not volatile.

But if we focus on volume and speed,

the former has relatively small volume, high speed, high cost

the latter has relatively big volume, low speed, low cost.